# How can I use a javascript variable as a background in an embedded style sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

What I'm trying to do this evening is to get my website to load a random background image every time you refresh the page.

Earlier in this project, I tried to get my background to interact with window size and screen resolution like [this website (for example)](http://ageofwonders.com/category/news/), and succeeded (you can see my code in the "html,body" selector in the embedded style sheet).

That was when I only used background1.jpg; now I want to randomly switch between several. I added the script below my title tag and I replaced the body tag with some script as well. This is what I'm working with now.

If I delete the background-related material from my style sheet, I succeed in randomizing the background, but that formatting is lost, which isn't acceptable. If I leave it as you see here, I retain the formatting, but fail to randomize. I want to have my cake and eat it, too. I've hit a wall and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<head>
      <title>Welcome to Cuhteekaloo!</title>

      <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
          var bgRand = Math.round(Math.random() * 5)
          bgOpt = new Array(6);
          bgOpt[0] = "background1.jpg";
          bgOpt[1] = "background2.jpg";
          bgOpt[2] = "background3.jpg";
          bgOpt[3] = "background4.jpg";
          bgOpt[4] = "background5.jpg";
          bgOpt[5] = "background6.jpg";
          var bgCurr = bgOpt[bgRand];
      </SCRIPT>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cuhteekaloo.css"/>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="jack.jpg"/>

      <style type="text/css">
          html,body {margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; overflow-y:hidden;   
          background: url(background1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;}
          body  {color:white;}
          img       {border:3px white solid;}
          p     {text-align:justify;}
          a:link, a:visited {color:white;}
          a:hover, a:active {color:orange;}
          .center   {text-align:center; display:block;}
      </style>
</head>

<script language="JAVASCRIPT">
document.write('<body background="' + bgCurr + '" text="white">')
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate when little, but big problems, get in your way of a great project.
 To begin, the issue is with the background changer and the randomizer.

The issue with the randomizer is that you have `bgRand` set as a variable meaning that it is loaded once at the beginning of the page loading. Try making it a function instead:

```
var bgRand = function(){return Math.round(Math.random() * 5);}
      bgOpt = new Array(6);
      bgOpt[0] = "background1.jpg";
      bgOpt[1] = "background2.jpg";
      bgOpt[2] = "background3.jpg";
      bgOpt[3] = "background4.jpg";
      bgOpt[4] = "background5.jpg";
      bgOpt[5] = "background6.jpg";
      var bgCurr = bgOpt[bgRand()];
```

The next issue is how your setting the background. You can do this much easier and make your "cake" much more delicious. Try this chunk of code:

```
document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+bgCurr+"')";
```

Now feel free to write the body tag with an id of "body". Like so:

```
<body id="body">
```

Finally I will give you a fork to eat your cake (AKA copy and paste source code):

```
     <head>    
            <title>Welcome to Cuhteekaloo!</title>

                  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
                      var bgRand = function(){return Math.round(Math.random() * 5);}
                      bgOpt = new Array(6);
                      bgOpt[0] = "background1.jpg";
                      bgOpt[1] = "background2.jpg";
                      bgOpt[2] = "background3.jpg";
                      bgOpt[3] = "background4.jpg";
                      bgOpt[4] = "background5.jpg";
                      bgOpt[5] = "background6.jpg";
                      var bgCurr = bgOpt[bgRand]();
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+bgCurr+"')";
                  </SCRIPT>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cuhteekaloo.css"/>
              <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="jack.jpg"/>

              <style type="text/css">
                  html,body {margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; overflow-y:hidden;   
background-image: url(background1.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center; 
background-attachment: fixed; 
                  body  {color:white;}
                  img       {border:3px white solid;}
                  p     {text-align:justify;}
                  a:link, a:visited {color:white;}
                  a:hover, a:active {color:orange;}
                  .center   {text-align:center; display:block;}
              </style>
        </head>
    <body id="body">
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: The function bit didn't work, but your css was helpful! If a background image was small or had unusual dimensions (not my M.O., mind you, but I was trying to find problems), your css provided a better focal point on a background, while my css covered the entire page. So what I ended up doing was deleting my background-image css property, and added your revised background-related css, to what remained of my background-related css. This gave me the ideal solution.
This cake is delicious.